# Python Beautifulsoup get texts before a certain tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code to run a python beautifulsoup to:

```
<html>
<head>  
<script> ... </head>
<title> ... </title>
<style> ... </title>
</head>

<body onload="nextHit()">
S. <a name="hit1"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">NO</span>. 178 H. <a name="hit2"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">NO</span>. 1323 / 46 OG <a name="hit3"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">No</span>. 12, 5977 (December, 1950)
<center>
<h2>...</h2>
<h3>...</h3>    
</center>
<br>
....Lines omitted for brevity (more brs, divs, prs)...
</body>
```

The thing is I only want to get the texts in the beginning of the body tag, just before the first center tag like so:

```
S. NO. 178 H. NO. 1323 / 46 OG No. 12, 5977 (December, 1950)
```

I have tried:

```
ogsourcing = soup.find('center').previousSibling
```

But I am getting just the last part like so:

```
. 12, 5977 (December, 1950)
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Version 2; based on OP's comment</sub>

---

1. `find()` the `<center>` element
2. Use `previous_siblings` to get an iterator with all the siblings
3. Loop over then, append the `.text` to an list
4. Reverse the list since we're looping from bottom to top
5. `''.join()` the list to get the desired string

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
    <head>
        <script></script>
        <title></title>
        <style></style>
    </head>

    <body onload="nextHit()">
        S. <a name="hit1"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">NO</span>. 178 H. <a name="hit2"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">NO</span>. 1323 / 46 OG <a name="hit3"></a><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">No</span>. 12, 5977 (December, 1950)
        <center>
        <h2>foo</h2>
        <h3>bar</h3>
        </center>
        <br>
        <em>test</em>
        <div>
            <em>test</em>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

res = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for sibling in soup.find('center').previous_siblings:
    res.append(sibling.text)

res.reverse()
res = ''.join(res)

print(res)
```

The above `print()` will output:

```
S. NO. 178 H. NO. 1323 / 46 OG No. 12, 5977 (December, 1950)
```

---

You might want to include a `.strip()` to get rid of any whitespaces and/or newlines

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! I forgot to mentioned that there are other elements tag in my html file/code. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Please edit your question to add all the details. Please post the HTML you\re dealing with.

Comment: Edited the part stating "omitted for brevity". test = soup.findAll(text=True, recursive=True) true enough it gave me all text even though those texts are not what I need. :)

Comment: "omitted for brevity" doesn't help? If you want me to update the answer you'll need to give the original html so we can test it using a [mre].

Comment: I added the tag structure, as to the content of these tags, I've omitted them.