# python beautifulsoup: how to find all before certain stop tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to find all tags of a certain kind  (class "nice") but excluding those after a certain other tag  (class "stop").

```html
<div class="nice"></div>
<div class="nice"></div>
<div class="stop">here should be the end of found items</div>
<div class="nice"></div>
<div class="nice"></div>
```

How do I accomplish this using bs4?
I found [this as a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296581/python-beautifulsoup-get-texts-before-a-certain-tag) but it appears a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example `.find_previous` to filter out unwanted tags:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<div class="nice">want 1</div>
<div class="nice">want 2</div>
<div class="stop">here should be the end of found items</div>
<div class="nice">do not want 1</div>
<div class="nice">do not want 2</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="nice"):
    if div.find_previous("div", class_="stop"):
        break
    print(div)
```

Prints:

```
<div class="nice">want 1</div>
<div class="nice">want 2</div>
```